# this.parent toggleClass of another child div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I can't figure this out.

When I click on the first toggleButton, I would like to target the first textContainerCollapsed and toggle its class with textContainerExpanded. And if I click on the second toggleButton, I would like the second textContainerCollapsed to toggle its class with textContainerExpanded and so on...

However, the result I have been getting is that all divs with the textContainerCollapsed are being affected regardless of which toggleButton I click.

js

```
$(function() {
    $(".toogleButton") click(function() {

        $(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent.children(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent.next(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent(".parent").next(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent(".parent").children(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

        //Also tried
        //$(this).parent(".parent").find(".textContainerCollapsed").toogleClass("textContainerExpanded",500);

    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <a href="#" class="toogleButton">
    </div>
    <div class="textContainerCollapsed">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <a href="#" class="toogleButton">
    </div>
    <div class="textContainerCollapsed">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.textContainerCollapsed
{
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.textContainerExpanded
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: May one presume you did try `toggleClass` rather than `toogleClass`?

Answer (score 1):

1st version using `closest()` and `find()`:

```
$(this)
  .closest(".parent")
  .find(".textContainerCollapsed")
  .toogleClass("textContainerExpanded");
```

2nd version using `parent()` and `next()`:

```
$(this)
  .parent()
  .next()
  .toogleClass("textContainerExpanded");
```

3rd version using `parent()` and `siblings()`:

```
$(this)
  .parent()
  .siblings()
  .toogleClass("textContainerExpanded");
```

Comment: or `$(".textContainerCollapsed", $(this).parents(".parent"))`

Comment: @JosephMarikle Though it is better to use `closest()` in your example, there are tons of other combinations :)

Comment: ooh nice! care to share why closest would be better or maybe a link?  I'm always one for optimized jQuery. :D

Comment: @JosephMarikle Well, at least because `parents(".parent")` return a set of all parents up to root which have class `.parent` (agree, it might happen to be more than one). Hence, it is slower and might give wrong results :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.toogleButton').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next()
           .toggleClass('textContainerCollapsed textContainerExpanded');
});
```